# Data stored in two separate tables, how to select the right table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Tables T1 and T2 in which, where in T1 contains column name 'Year' which saves year information and T2 contains column name as 'P_year' which saves year information.

In the Table T1, I saved some data for the years '2011,2012,2013,2014'. In the Table T2, I am saving the data for the years '2015,2016...and it goes on.

Now, I had developed a common webform to view the results, wherein I placed a dropdown for the year to choose all the years 2011,2012,2013,2014,2015...

And I am confused how to choose...like if the user has selected any particular year, How should I choose the right select statement with the right table...i.e.if the user has selected 2013,then I have to choose select statement related to table T1 and if the user has selected 2015, then I have to choose select statement related to table T2 ?

And if the user doesn't selects the year,How should I display all the data from both tables ?

```
if(year == "2011" !!year == "2012"!!year == "2013"!!year == "2014")
{
query1 = "select * from T1 where year ="Selected Year";
}
else if (year == "2015")
{
query2 = "select * from T2 where year ="2015";
}
else
{
query1 = "select * from T1 where year in('2011','2012','2013','2014');
query2 = "select * from T2 where year ="2015";
}
```

So,I can handle the execution in choosing the right query to execute if the user has selected any particular year. But issue rise up, if the user doesn't selects the year, I have to display the data from both tables executing both queries...like I have shown above in the last else statement.

So, Is there any way to write code in a optimized way. Note:- Right here, I am just showing up a single lined query statement,but in real it exists for 5 or 6 lines of select statement.

Anyone please help me out in this regard.

Thanking You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'2011,2012,2013,2014'
'2015,2016 and so on'

1. dropdownlist included all Years
2. convert dropdownlist.selectedValue to int
3. if(int < 2015)
       query1 
   else
       query2

Comment: What if the user doesn't selects the year ? Its a custom selection query based generation. Its not mandatory to select the year. If he selects particular year, need to show that particular year information or else need to show all the years information from both the Tables.

Comment: if dun select year, then join the queries

Comment: Not all the column names in both the tables are same. They might hold same values but the column names are different in both the names.

Comment: based on the output u need, cast column name as 'something' then union together, you might need to checkout SQL union query.